# Batch file scripting playing with the directories

Tags: batch-file

```
FORFILES /p E:\test_folderpath\ /D -2 /S /C "cmd /c echo @isdir @path "|findstr "FALSE"|findstr /v "E:\test_folderpath\testtest\log"
```

This code is showing all files that have FALSE string even their extensions is different. And they came from on different directories, and all their directories have a SC folder (Success).

For example if I echo the path/file on the command line this is the output:

FALSE "C:\tester\test\test\waedsa.tmp"

What I want to do is to get all those FALSE files and to move them into SC folder on their respective directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is much simpler than your current code. There is no need for FINDSTR or pipes. I use find and replace to test if @path contains the excluded file. I also pretend that the file is actually a directory, so that `@path\..\` refers to the parent directory of the file. It is not obvious, but this works!

Note that this will attempt to move files that are already in an SC folder, but this will fail (a good thing) because the SC folders do not have their own SC folders. I redirect stderr to NUL so the expected error message is hidden.

```
forfiles /p E:\test_folderpath\ /d -2 /s /c "cmd /v:on /c set "file=@path"&if @isdir==FALSE if !file:E:\test_folderpath\testtest\log=! neq !file! move /y @path @path\..\sc >nul 2>nul"
```

Or you could use FIND (or FINDSTR) to exclude the unwanted file:

```
forfiles /p E:\test_folderpath\ /d -2 /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @path|find /i "E:\test_folderpath\testtest\log" >nul || move /y @path @path\..\sc >nul 2>nul"
```

If you know the exact name of the file to exclude (call it log.txt for this example), then it is even simpler:

```
forfiles /p E:\test_folderpath\ /d -2 /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE if /i @path neq "E:\test_folderpath\testtest\log.txt"  move /y @path @path\..\sc >nul 2>nul"
```

Comment: Based on your `@path\..\ `  note, I just tested `cd "C:\Windows\System32"\..\ `  and it returned the `C:\Windows` directory. That is an awesome trick to know.

Comment: I already did this and it's working. But I have last problem, I need to capture the path or to store the path to the variable. I need to store the @path\..\sc. Because, before I moved out the files to SC. I need to go through the something.exe to pass the files. And something.exe will process the file and it will create a successful file for SC. The parameters of something.exe is, start "" something.exe "E:\test_folderpath\test"(where the files coming from) "E:\test_folderpath\SC"(where the files will be send) "E:\test_folderpath\test"(Original directory). So I need to store the \..\sc

Comment: No, you do not need to put the path into a variable. Just call your "something.exe" from within the FORFILES command. It sounds like you want to do that instead of MOVE.